# Running SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7 connected to a domain

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have successfully installed SharePoint 2010 on my Windows 7 machine. My computer is a work machine and is on a domain. I'm trying to set up the computer to work completely standalone without having to connect to the domain. So far I haven't been able to get that working. I can connect to my work domain via VPN and everything works. But I want to be able to use SharePoint without being connected. I've read about a command called **New-SPConfigurationDatabase** that might be able to help but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: This is probably a question better suited for SharePoint Stack Exchange. Anyways, how did you install it? In a VM or something like this, https://spradip.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/installing-sharepoint-2010-in-windows-7-64-bit/?

Comment: Wait... not connected to any domain? how are you planing authentication? (not sure it can be done, but you wanna?). Is your SQL server ALSO in your Windows 7 machine? no? how is going to connect to the DB? I am confused as to what are you trying to acomplish.

Comment: Also, your questions says "connected to a domain" but you are actually asking how to run it DISCONNECTED from a domain. it is contradictory.

Comment: My setup is running on my machine not on a vm. And I meant to say that computer is on a domain and connects to a domain controller. When Im not connected to the domain controller my setup wont work. And I dont want to always be logged into work. Sorry about the confusion.